# Behat + Mink don't work with proxy (DNS cannot resolve domain name)

Tags: dns, proxy, bdd, behat, mink

I have a simple [Behat](http://behat.org/) feature that uses Mink for testing webapp which domain is, say `http://myapp.localhost` (I have a record like `127.0.0.1 myapp.localhost` in my `hosts` file).

The problem is, when I run the feature, all what Mink driver gets when it browses to any URL in the app (e.g. with `When I go to "/some/url"` step) is an error page from proxy-server, saying that domain `myapp.localhost` cannot be resolved. Proxy server address is set by env. variable: `export http_proxy=...`.

External websites work just fine (like an [example with Wikipedia](http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html#writing-your-first-web-feature) from Behat docs).

My browser can reach the app because there is a setting telling the browser not to use proxy when domain is `*.localhost`.

How to force Mink to ignore proxy?

Spent an hour today to pin down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I use is not very elegant, but it's the simplest way I can think of. I have some sort of build tool written in Bash, which has a following function to invoke Behat:

```shell
function run_behat {
  local http_proxy_backup=$http_proxy
  export http_proxy=;

  bin/behat $@ # passing all args to behat
  # if you use phar version of behat, it will be like `php behat.phar $@`

  export http_proxy=$http_proxy_backup
}
```

Basically, I just temporarily set `http_proxy` to empty value, call behat, and then restore `http_proxy` initial value.

It is invoked from my script like that:

```shell
if [ $1 == "behat" ]; then 
  run_behat ${*:2}; # pass all args but 1st
fi
```